# What is the difference between a continuous map and an identification map?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, open-map

According to the definitions I have, the map in topology is **continuous** if the preimage of every open set is open. The map $f:X \to Y$ is called an **identification** map if it is continuous, surjective and also if the open sets of Y are exactly the subsets $A\subset Y$ with the property that $f^{-1}(A)\subset X$ is open in $X$.

I do not understand how the last condition of the identification map definition is different from the preimage of open sets being open in the definition of a continuous map. I get that an identification map must be surjective, which is different from a continuous map but it seems that there is more that I am missing.

Comment: I think by $B$ you mean $Y$, right? A function $f : X \to Y$ is a **continuous map** if the following holds: $$\forall U \subseteq Y: \ U \textrm{ is open in } Y \implies f^{-1}(U) \textrm{ is open in } X.$$ Is a **quotient map** if its surjective and the following holds: $$\forall U \subseteq Y: \ U \textrm{ is open in } Y \iff f^{-1}(U) \textrm{ is open in } X.$$ (Note that, the "$\Longrightarrow$" gives us the continuity of $f$, and the "$\Longleftarrow$" is an aditional condition).

Comment: éxactly' is the key word.

Comment: Continuity says $A$ open in $Y$ implies $f^{-1}(A)$ open in $X$. Identification changes "implies" to "if and only if."

Comment: Yes, I meant $Y$, sorry for the errors. I think I get it now, thank you very much!