# What is the difference between an identification and an open identification?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, open-map

[I asked a similar question yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263805/what-is-the-difference-between-a-continuous-map-and-an-identification-map) but studying my course further, I stumbled upon a definition of **open identification** that confused me. It says that open identification is an identification that is also an open map.

The definition of open map that I have states that it is a function that maps open sets to open sets. Now, to my understanding, identification is in fact a continuous, surjective and open map. The definition of open identification does not really make sense then, so I might misunderstood some of the definitions...

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Small note: It may be nice if you insert the definition of an identification map here as well, so as to make it self-contained. Or you could simply use the word "quotient" instead, since that is more common terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I'll remark that what you call an "identification" map is actually what one usually calls a "quotient" map.

The following *is* true:

> A continuous and surjective open map is a quotient map.

However, not all quotient maps are open. Let $f : X \to Y$ be a quotient map. The issue is that you may have an open subset of $X$ which is **not** of the form $f^{-1}(B)$ for any $B \subset Y$.

In fact, call a subset $A \subset X$ **saturated** if $A  = f^{-1}(B)$ for some $B \subset Y$. Then, what is true is that a quotient map takes a *saturated* open set to an open set.

---

Lastly, to dispel all doubts, here is an example (from Munkres) of a quotient map that is not an open map:

Let $X = [0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$, and let $Y = [0, 2]$. (Both are given the subspace topology from $\Bbb R$.) Define $f : X \to Y$ by
$$f(x) := \begin{cases} x & \text{for } x \in [0, 1], \\  x - 1 & \text{for } x \in [2, 3].\end{cases}$$
I leave it to you to verify that $f$ is a quotient map. However, the image of the open set $[0, 1] \subset X$ is not open in $Y$. Thus, $f$ is not an open map.
(Note that $[0, 1]$ is not saturated since it intersects $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ but does not contain it completely.)

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. I still have a question though. If for a map to be quotient the preimages of it sets need to be open, then how is that different from a continuous map?

Comment: @Slowflake: Isn't that exactly the question you asked yesterday?

Comment: Maybe but I got this explanation: "Is a quotient map if its surjective and the following holds: ∀⊆:  is open in ⟺−1() is open in ." Doesn't that mean that there cannot be open sets that are not preimages of open sets?

Comment: No. It is not mean. It means that if an open set $U$ is a preimage of a set $V$, then $V$ must be open. But you may very well have open sets which are not preimages of *anything*. (I.e., open sets which are not saturated.)

Comment: Ohh, I see it now. The example you gave makes sense now. Thanks a lot!